# typescript destructuring and implicit any

Tags: typescript

Please direct my to some documentation as I struggle to understand why there is a difference in compiling this two implementations:

```
  function getPropImplicitAny<T, K extends keyof T>(p: K, buffer: T): T[K] {
    const { [p]: value } = buffer; // element implicitly has an 'any' type
                                   // because T has not index signature
    return value;
  }
  function getPropTyped<T, K extends keyof T>(p: K, buffer: T): T[K] {
    const value = buffer[p]; // value:T[K]
    return value;
  }
```

In my view both functions know the same about the structure of the `T` type and its relations with the `K`. Both of them access member of `T` by index syntax. Yet the first one fails to compile in strict mode.
Why?

Comment: What version of ts are you using ? I think de-structuring has been improved several times. Your code works in the playground with all strict options : http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20getPropImplicitAny%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(p%3A%20K%2C%20buffer%3A%20T)%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20%5Bp%5D%3A%20value%20%7D%20%3D%20buffer%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20value%3B%0D%0A%7D

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are describing has been fixed in typescript 3.2. [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24661) issue describes your exact problem and it was included in typescript 3.2